# How to get the LDAP error codes from exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, exception, ldap

I create LDAP connection using `DirectoryEntry`

My issue if there is some error I have to know the code of the error

My code:

```
var domain = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ONLINE-AD"];

var directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + domain);
directoryEntry.Username = model.userName;
directoryEntry.Password = model.password;

var directorySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(directoryEntry);

try
{
    var f = directorySearcher.FindOne();
    result = true;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    result = false;
}
```

When exception I sew the code here:

[image]

How can I get the [error code](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/newyork-platform-administration/page/administer/reference-pages/reference/r_LDAPErrorCodes.html) out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to match it with some regex. For example:

```
catch (DirectoryServicesCOMException ex)
{
    Regex reg = new Regex(@"^(.*data )(?<ecode>\d*)");
    if(reg.IsMatch(ex.ExtendedErrorMessage))
    {
        GroupCollection groups = reg.Match(ex.ExtendedErrorMessage).Groups;
        errorCode = groups["ecode"].Value;
    }
}
```

The regex could probably be simplified a bit, but basically it is looking for

- The start of the line - `^`
- Any amount of any characters up until "data " and puts it in the first group - `(.*data )`
- Any amount of digits and then puts it in a group named ecode - `(?<ecode>\d*)`

This will only work under the assumption that all error messages have the same format.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you cannot get the origin LDAP error code from numeric params of DirectoryServicesCOMException because [ADSI LDAP provider maps all the LDAP error codes to Win32 error codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adsi/win32-error-codes-for-adsi).

You can get next:

```cs
var hresult = -2147023570; // -> 0x8007052e
// 0x8007052e is "LDAP_INVALID_CREDENTIALS Supplied credential is not valid."
var win32errorCode = (ushort)(0xFFFF & hresult); // --> 1326
// 1326 is "ERROR_LOGON_FAILURE The user name or password is incorrect."
```

List of [ADSI System Error Codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adsi/win32-error-codes).

Comment: But I tried to login a user that has to reset password for first time (error code 773) and not 52e(1326)

Comment: It looks like the only way to get it is parsing *error message* ;(